# Replace the digits of a number with subsequent higher digits

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Given a number I want to replace each digit with the next digit that is larger. If there is no next larger digit leave the digit as it was.

Eg : Input : 1234, Output - 2344

Since in Oracle we can process everything row by row, I tried first to separate the digits of number into rows by using the below query.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('1234','[[:digit:]]',1,LEVEL) txt
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length('1234');
```

The query will give me this result.

```
TXT
----------------
1
2
3
4
```

But I am stuck in here, how to compare the two rows and replace them with the largest.

*Attempted expansion and clarification based on comments:*

Treat the number as a string of digits. For each digit, find the first digit among the remaining digits to the right of the current one, that has a higher value than the current digit. That may not be the highest-value digit in the string, or even the highest among all the digits to the right, it is just the first higher value encountered. If there is no higher value then keep the current digit intact. Only consider following digits, preceding ones are ignored.

Some examples:

```
1234 -> 2344
1357 -> 3577
1157 -> 5577
1245638 -> 2456888
```

Breaking down the last one:

- Digit 1 is `1`; the first digit in the remaining string `245638` that is higher than `1` is **`2`**.
- Digit 2 is `2`; the first digit in the remaining string `45638` that is higher than `2` is **`4`**.
- Digit 3 is `4`; the first digit in the remaining string `5638` that is higher than `4` is **`5`**.
- Digit 4 is `5`; the first digit in the remaining string `638` that is higher than `5` is **`6`**.
- Digit 5 is `6`; the first digit in the remaining string `38` that is higher than `6` is **`8`**.
- Digit 6 is `3`; the first digit in the remaining string `8` that is higher than `3` is **`8`**.
- Digit 7 is `8`; no subsequent digit is higher then `8` so keep existing digit **`8`**.

Comment: @Nicholas - All the digits that were smaller than 5, should be replaced by 5. Expected O/P for your input is 5557.

Comment: @arunb2w . . . Are the numbers all 4 digits?

Comment: @Gordon - The numbers are not restricted to 4 digits. There can be any number of digits. But they are all integers no floating point numbers.Thanks

Comment: @arunb2w - there still seems to be some confusion and your logic was only really explained in comments, so I've tried to summarise in the question. Please check I've got it right... if not clarify further of course, or roll back my edit *8-)

Comment: @arunb2w, please tell us what this is for - I'm dying of curiosity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some clarification in comments:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT LEVEL AS pos,
    ROWNUM AS txt_order,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR ('1245638','[[:digit:]]',1,LEVEL) AS txt
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH('1245638')
),
v AS (
  SELECT t1.pos, t1.txt,
    MIN(t2.txt) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY t2.pos) as new_txt
  FROM t t1
  LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t2.pos > t1.pos AND t2.txt > t1.txt
  GROUP BY t1.pos, t1.txt
)
SELECT LISTAGG(NVL(new_txt, txt), NULL) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pos) AS OUTPUT
FROM v;

OUTPUT 
--------
2456888
```

The `t` CTE is just your original query. Now the `v` CTE is finding the first digit later in the list which is larger than the current one; the `nvl` uses the current digit if there isn't one larger. The `listagg` just sticks the digits back together in the right order.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d4be/1) of the same logic, but using a recursive CTE instead of the connect-by to generate the digits, just so multiple values can be 'converted' in one go from a table. Which gives:

```
ORIGINAL                                 OUTPUT 
---------------------------------------- --------
1234                                     2344     
1157                                     5577     
1357                                     3577     
1245638                                  2456888
```

Comment: Alex - You are really great. Your query looks really good for unique digits but because of the with clause Order by txt, for some inputs it behaves unexpectedly.
For example if the input is "1245638" the output from the query is "2456688" but the expected O/P is 2456888

Comment: I think u misunderstood my question wrongly. Your O/P shows that you are replacing each digit by adding 1, but I need to replace the each digit with the next largest digit in that number.
`For Example in the above Input 1245638,
1 replaced with ==> next largest digit 2
2 replaced with ==> next largest digit 4
4 replaced with ==> next largest digit 5
5 replaced with ==> next largest digit 6
6 replaced with ==> next largest digit 8
3 replaced with ==> next largest digit 8
8 replaced with ==> no next largest digit so 8 itself`
So the output should be 2456888

Comment: @arunb2w - I am not just adding 1. The second digit is 2; the next largest digit in the original number was 3 (the sixth digit), not 4. And when it gets to the sixth digit which is 3, the next largest digit in the original number was 4, not 8. You expected result would match a starting number of 1245688, not 1245638. So yes, at least one of us still doesn't understand your logic... Maybe you mean 'the next digit that is larger', rather than 'the next-largest digit'?

Comment: Sorry if I confused you guys.@Alex As u said it should be replaced with next digit that is larger. Probably the above comment that explains my requirement should clarify your doubts

Comment: I still don't understand what it's for - but I'm upvoting this answer anyway! :)